# Unity cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, websocket

Hello i want to parse data that i get from a websocket server but it says "cannot convert from 'string' to 'int'

---

And when I do then it gives me a wrong number
Example:

- real value: -11.6666342423411
- value it says: -1.166663424234E + 16

```
    void Update()
    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(e.Data);
            Debug.Log(data);
            // position.x = int.Parse(e.Data["position"]["x"]);
            // position.y = int.Parse(e.Data["position"]["y"]);
            // Debug.Log(position);
            // gameObject.transform.position = position;

            // float rotation = data["rotation"];
            // rb.rotation = rotation;
        };
    }
```

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using WebSocketSharp;
using SimpleJSON;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    Vector2 position;

    WebSocket ws;
    void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");
        ws.Connect();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(e.Data);
            Debug.Log(e.Data["position"]);
            // position.x = int.Parse(e.Data["position"]["x"]);
            // position.y = int.Parse(e.Data["position"]["y"]);
            // Debug.Log(position);
            // gameObject.transform.position = position;

            // float rotation = data["rotation"];
            // rb.rotation = rotation;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: in `e.Data["position"]`, the string `"position"` must be a position in the array

Comment: @rustyBucketBay `JSON.Parse` retuns no array but a JsonObject which works similar to a Dictionary ...

Answer (score 0):

What you get parsed is the value of

```
-116666342423411
```

because [`int.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_) by default doesn't use a decimal point ... because there is none in an `int`. And then it returns an `int` and Unity just displays it in sceintific notation.

---

What you rather want to use is [`float.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.single.parse?view=net-5.0) since your value is supposed to be a floating point value.

Or actually now that I see you are using [SimpleJson](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/SimpleJSON) you can also simply use `JsonNode.AsFloat` since they already have an implementation for that.

Or if you would also use the `SimpleJSONUnity.cs (Extension file)` then you can actually just use `JsonNode.ReadVector2`!

---

And then you also want to access these values not in `e.Data` but rather in your parsed json node

```
position.x = float.Parse(data["position"]["x"].Value);
position.y = float.Parse(data["position"]["y"].Value);
```

or as said

```
position.x = data["position"]["x"].AsFloat();
position.y = data["position"]["y"].AsFloat();
```

or (using the extensions)

```
position = data["position"].ReadVector2();
```

---

And then in general let me immediately tell you that it won't work the way you have it!

You want to attach the listener **ONCE**!

And also most of Unity API can only be used in the Unity main thread and `OnMessage` most probably is called async.

You code should rather be e.g.

```
public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Rigidbody2D rb;

    private readonly ConcurrentQueue<Action> _actions = new ConcurrentQueue<Action>();

    WebSocket ws;
    void Start()
    {
        ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8080");

        ws.OnMessage += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // dispatch this into the main thread so it is executed in the next Update call
            _actions.Enqueue(() =>
            {
                JSONNode data = JSON.Parse(e.Data);
            
                var x = float.Parse(data["position"]["x"].Value);     
                //var x = data["position"]["x"].AsFloat();
                var y = float.Parse(data["position"]["y"].Value);     
                //var y = data["position"]["y"].AsFloat();

                var position = new Vector2(x, y);
                //var position = data["position"].ReadVector2();

                Debug.Log($"Received position {position.ToString("G8")}");
                // NOTE: you should not set anything via Transform
                // otherwise you break the physics and collision detection
                rb.MovePosition(position);

                var rotation = float.Parse(data["rotation"].Value); 
                //var rotation = data["rotation"].AsFloat();
                rb.MoveRotation(rotation);
            });
        };

        ws.Connect();
    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        while(_actions.Count > 0 && _actions.TryDequeue(out var action))
        {
            action?.Invoke();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Then it says to me cannot convert string to int in Lines where you set the x and y

Comment: @robinnlmn Could you show me the JSON format you are receiving?

Comment: {"position":{"x":-15.184359550476075,"y":-5.733031749725342},"rotation":-322.5946350097656,"id":"1"}

Comment: @robinnlmn can you check your code ... I just copied it exactly as it is into a new project together with the SimpleJson and the WebSocket stuff and have no errors ...

Comment: @robinnlmn the one of my answer

Comment: The threading doesn't work for me? Which import do i need to have?

Comment: and for the `ConcurrentQueue` you need `using System.Collections.Concurrent;` and for the `Action` it is `using System;` (in addition to the ones you already have) if that is what you mean ;)

Comment: Now i get an error: unity object reference not set to an instance of an object simplejson.JSONNode.Parse